# Show that 2n "1" digits subtract n "2" digits is a perfect square.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I came across a difficult question in my IB HL Math book while revising for my Sequences and Series test that I wanted to share. I can't seem to figure it out.

[image: The Question]

Here's how I approached it so far:

1. I found a series to generate 2n "1" digits and n "2" digits respectively:
   $$
   \sum_{k=1}^{2n}10^{k-1}
   $$
   $$
   \sum_{k=1}^{n}2\cdot10^{k-1}
   $$

Then, I used the sum formula:

$$
S_{n} = \frac{U_{1}(1-r^{n})}{1 - r}
$$
For generating n digits of 1:
$$
S_{2n} = \frac{1(1-10^{2n})}{-9}
$$
For generating n digits of 2:
$$
S_{n} = \frac{2(1-10^{n})}{-9}
$$

At this point, the question asks you to show that, when you subtract these terms, you are left with a perfect square.

If you do subtract these algebraically, you are left with:
$$
\frac{1+10^{2n} - 2\cdot10^{n}}{9}
$$

What I thought of doing was attempting to get the square root of this. The denominator leaves 3, but there doesn't seem to be a way to simplify the square root of the numerator expression and show that it's an integer.

Can somebody help me on a method to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: While you've gotten an answer, here's how you could have seen it for yourself: First, $10^{2n} = (10^n)^2$. Then just sort the numerator for powers, to get $(10^n)^2 + 2\cdot 10^n + 1$. At that point, you should be able to see the pattern of the binomial formula $a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 = (a+b)^2$ with $a=10^n$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint**: You are almost done. Observe that
$$1 + 10^{2n} - 2\cdot10^n = (10^n - 1)^2.$$

Comment: Awesome! Then I should be able to prove by induction that $10^{n} - 1$ is divisible by 3. Thanks! (will accept your answer in 8 mins... sorry, don't have much rep over here on the Math version of Stack Overflow :p)

Comment: @MCKapur No worries, I have that limit as well!

Comment: @leemes Right, but we haven't shown that 10^{n} - 1 is perfectly divisible by 3.

Comment: @MCKapur: The original expression quite obviously gives an integer, and since everything done was just equivalence transformations, it is obvious that it still describes an integer. The number that is squared is clearly a rational number (quotient of two integers). Any rational number whose square is integer is itself an integer.

Comment: @celtschk Ah, okay. Yep. I understand.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following :
$$
\eqalign{
& \sum_{k=1}^{2n}10^{k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}2\cdot 10^{k-1} = \cr
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{n+k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{k-1} \cr
&=  \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{n+k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{k-1} \cr
&= 10^n \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{k-1} \cr
&= (10^n-1) \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}10^{k-1} \cr
&= (10^n-1) \cdot {10^n -1 \over 10 -1} = {(10^n-1)^2 \over 3^2 } = \biggl({10^n -1 \over 3}\biggr)^2
}
$$